# Why is $provide only available in the 'angular.mock.module' function, and $q only available in the 'angular.mock.inject' function?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine

I am mocking out a service for an AngularJS Unit Test. I'm using the `$provide` service to replace the 'real' service with the mocked out one (a [plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Gbr1N?p=preview) of this is available):

```
describe('My Controller', function () {

    var $scope;
    var $provide;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function (_$provide_) {

        $provide = _$provide_;

    }));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q){

        var mockMyService = {
            getAll : function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve([
            { itemText: "Foo" },
            { itemText: "Bar" }
                ]);

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };

        $provide.value('myService', mockMyService);

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope });

        $rootScope.$apply();

    }));

    it('Has two items defined', function () {
        expect($scope.items.length).toEqual(2);
    });
});
```

This works just fine. However, I don't like the fact that I am using an `angular.mock.module` function simply to give a reference to the `$provide` service which is then used in the `angular.mock.inject` function below. But if I add `$provide` as a parameter to the `angular.mock.inject` function directly instead, I get an 'unknown provider' error.

It occurs to me that I could put all the mocking code in the `angular.mock.module` function. But then I have a similar issue with the `$q` reference, which I need as my mocked service has to return a promise.

In other words, if I add a `$q` parameter to the `angular.mock.module` function then I also get an 'unknown provider' error.

Is there a way to simplify this? Obviously what I have works but it doesn't feel quite right, somehow. I feel that I lack understanding of why some providers are available in `inject` functions and others are available in `module` functions.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't use `$provide` within the `inject` function because the former registers providers for the latter to use. Take a look:

```
describe('...', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.constant('someValue', 'foobar');
        });

        inject(function(someValue) {
            var value = someValue; // will be 'foobar';
        });
    });
});
```

You can though write your test this way:

```
describe('...', function() {
    var serviceMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        serviceMock = {
           someMethod: function() { ... }
        };

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('service', serviceMock);
        });

        inject(function(service) {
            ...                         
        });
    });
});
```

In fact, you don't even need to implement the mocked service before injecting it with `$provide`:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    serviceMock = {};

    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('service', serviceMock);
    });

    inject(function(service) {
        ...                         
    });
});

it('tests something', function() {
    // Arrange
    serviceMock.someMethod = function() { ... }

    // Act
    // does something

    // Assert
    expect(...).toBe(...);
});
```

Here's a [Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/mUSLEVP6fLiOmEFXHm9u?p=preview) illustrating mostly of the above.

Comment: This is very nice and it works... as long as your not using a Promise. Here is a plunk showing my original example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Gbr1N?p=preview
And here is a fork updated with the technique you suggest: http://plnkr.co/edit/ptAWcb?p=preview
The mock service is not getting assigned; it looks as though something is interfering with the timing.

Comment: I wonder why I can't get hold of the '$q' library from the 'module' function? If I could, then I would have everything I need to create the mock service there.

Comment: @Holf You can use a promise, but you need to move things around a little bit first. Check out this updated [Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fi1SQq).

Comment: @Holf You can't get a instance of the `$q` service within the `module` function because Angular doesn't inject any service into it. The proper way to do that is by using the `inject` function. That's by design, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, this is all really cool and it now makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @MichaelBenford great answer! btw I was wondering what was the diff between **angular.mock.module** vs **angular.module**

Comment: @FutuToad `angular.module` is used to define a module while `angular.mock.module` is used to load an existing module into memory so tests can get access to its content (services, factories, directives etc). `mock.module` is also used to configure the injector so you can provide mock objects for any injectable service. Take a look at the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.module) for more information.

Comment: @MichaelBenford thx, but in my tests: **beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));**
    makes all my tests pass just as when I do: **beforeEach(module('app'));**

Comment: @FutuToad `module` is a global alias for `angular.mock.module`, as said in the docs: `This function is also published on window for easy access.`.

Comment: I studied the differences between Holf's [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fi1SQq) and @michael-benford's [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ptAWcb?p=preview) to figure out why Michael's worked and why Holf's didn't.   At first, I thought it was due to the arrangement order of Michael's code but it turns out there was a simple error in Holf's.  Holf's just needed to initialize mockMyService to an empty object and then not overwrite it when defining the getAll mocked method.  That way the provided mock service gets used.  Updated Holf's [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A2uisLWuzhCfJ1Noys8R?p=preview).

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me when I had to wrap a service which used `$q` and seems quite clean:

```
var _ServiceToTest_;
beforeEach(function () {
    module('module.being.tested');
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('ServiceToMock', function ($q, $rootScope) {
            var service = ...;
            // use $q et al to heart's content
            return service;
        });
    });
    inject(function (_ServiceToTest_) {
        ServiceToTest = _ServiceToTest_;
    });
});

it('...', function () { /* code using ServiceToTest */ });
```

The trick was to use `$provide.factory` instead of `$provide.value`.